# Java custom annotation to restricted access to method

Tags: java, annotations

I am building an application on two layer. Web layer and business layer.

Inside the business layer I have some public method that can be called within the business layer or from the web layer.

I only want some of these methods being called from the web layer (the safe one).

I was wondering if I can create a annotation in my business layer, for example `@Public` which means I can call this method from the web layer, and `@Private` so I should not use this method from the web layer.

And when I try to call a `@private` method from the web layer (in eclipse) it gives me a warning?

As well: Can I have a way to list automatically all this method private and public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't make Eclipse use annotation to determine whether you can access a method from a certain file. For this to be possible Eclipse would have to know whether the file is part of the web layer or the business layer.

In order to list all methods having a certain annotation, you could use reflection at runtime. In Eclipse there might be filters, but I don't know of any annotation based filters.

Maybe you should choose another approach, I'll shortly describe how we do that:

We have two interfaces that our services may implement:

- one public interface that contains all the methods the web layer may see
- one private interface that contains all the methods internal to the business logic

We split those interfaces into two eclipse projects - one public api project and one implementation project that contains the services and internal api - and just allow access to the public api project from the web layer.

Since our services (EJB 3.0) need an interface, we have to add the internal one, if we have internal methods. However, with other technology (like EJB 3.1) you might also just provide the public interface.

Another approach might be to split the interfaces into two packages, e.g. `myproject.api.pub` (public is a keyword) and `myproject.api.internal`, and then use package based filters in Eclipse.

Comment: Yeas sure. Right now I have one project which the business, and another one which is the web (using jsf). But I should have the web project, the interface and the business. But as said before we dont want to change the design now, the projects is already to advance

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes up in my mind is that this would only be needed in a bad-designed two-layer app.

You can use access control to make sure that the web gui can only access the safe methods, and keep other methods to the business layer.

It is probably possible to just make those "public" methods that you don't want to be used by the web interface private; that way you can use them in the public, safe, methods in the business logic.

Though without knowing how your project is set up, giving concrete examples is kind of impossible.

But say; you can have:
com.somecompany.gui > contains all web-gui stuff
com.somecompany.logic > contains business logic.

In the logic package, you create classes that have public methods to be used from gui, and private or - if needed by other logic components - package private (protected) methods that cannot be accessed from the gui package. That way you can separate your logic from the interface without having a need for the annotation you want to make.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Indeed the design is wrong, but for the security we want to achieve it is enough (We dont want to seperate the two layer now, it is too late). Good idea about the protected pckg. I am going to have a look at it now

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd say: yes, it could work. At least to produce compiler warnings.

We have the `@Override` annotation for methods. This annotation is used for a similar reason: verify at compile time, that certain conditions are met. In this case: the annotated methods overrides a method from a superclass or it implements an interface method or an abstract method. If the *verifier* finds out, the this is not the case, then the compiler will produce a compile time error.

So it should be possible here too. We could think of an annotations like

```
 @Layer("servicelayer")                // class annotation

 @Private(layer="servicelayer")        // method annotation
```

And now we could verify at compile time, that annotated methods can only be called from classes that have the same layer annotation. If the condition is not met, the compiler could produce a warning (iaw: the compiler could detect, if we accidentally call an internal service layer method from a web layer class.

Comment: That would require a plugin, wouldn't it? AFAIK, plain eclipse would ignore those annotations.

Comment: @Thomas - honestly, I don't know. We definitely need an annotation processor and if *that* is called by the eclipse compiler automatically, eclipse might be able to display the compiler warnings as markers.

Comment: Thx for ur reply, well I dont really want it at compilation time (we are using some ant script to compile) I really want it during development

Comment: @user789148 if you enable automatic builds in eclipse you'd get the warnings during development, since eclipse would compile the class behind the scenes each time you change it.

Comment: @user789148 - During *development*, iaw, during *typing* requires a somewhat intelligent editor. The idea of annotations is do some work at compile time with the help of annotation processors. You're favorite solution would require an eclipse plugin.

Comment: To solve the problem, I think all method are gojng to be authenicated. (user admin for the internal one, other use for the one from the web layer). Then I am going to throw an exception that need to be catch